# Storybook Rollup Rudux and Context API Error when converting MUI

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, rollup, themeprovider

I want to convert the Mui template into storybook. I successfully converted some components while some components are using context API and redux internally. After successfully converting them into `npm` package, I used `npm pack` . Now I'm facing this error whenever I'm using components that use the context API or redux but components that are not using those are working fine.

I already pass my provider inside my entry file during the build.

[image]

Comment: Does your npm package declare React as a peer dependency? The error message looks like the React dependency itself is somehow not found.